# Understanding consequences of spacetime relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

If I understood right, time flows slower where there is more gravitational force (or to be more precise, as it was pointed out to me, where gravitational potential is lower), compared to where there is less: that means that if we put a first timer in a point A in which there is more gravity, then it will say that less time has passed than a second clock in a point B in which there is less gravity.

**QUESTION 1**

But does it mean that phenomenons actually occur slower in high-gravity-zones, so if I’m in a low-gravity-zone and I throw a ball towards a high-gravity-zone, it slows down? And is this difference noticeable by an observer in the low-gravity-zone, if he is able to see also the high-gravity-zone and the ball entering it?

**QUESTION 2**

If yes, how can a third-party-observer tell the difference between a fast-moving-ball in a high-gravity-zone and a slow-moving-ball in a low-gravity-zone? Is there a way to have an “absolut value” of speed (for example, but also for other physical quantities) that doesn’t depend on the time-zone? Because otherwise, it seems to me that all measurements would be useful (or make sense) only as long as there are no differences in gravity between places, or the differences are negligible.

**QUESTION 3**

Imagine I’m in point A (a high-gravity-zone) and a friend of mine is in point B (a low-gravity-zone). If question 1 is correct (so phenomenons actually change their speed) the sound waves coming from my mouth, as i speak to my friend, should speed up while moving to the low-gravity-zone (where time moves faster) and so he should listen to a pitched up and sped-up version of what i said. Is this correct? If not, how is it?

**QUESTION 4**

If question 1 is not correct, so a third party observer doesn’t see the ball slowing down, what does he see? How does time work?

**NOTES**

Disclaimer: i’m not studying physics and I have just finished high school, so I barely have a grasp of what general relativity is and its conception of time from some books that I’ve read. I’ve tried to ask this question in the most meaningful way possible but my competences are limited so there might be some confusion.

Comment: *Time flows slower where there is more gravitational force.* It’s actually [gravitational *potential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential), not force, that affects time.

Comment: For example, time runs more slowly at the center of the Earth than at the surface, even though the force at the center is zero.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation): “The lower the gravitational potential…, the slower time passes.”

Comment: @Ghoster ok, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes relative to you it slows down. If the ball was wearing a watch, you would see its watch moving slower than your watch. But in the balls reference frame, it would feel as if its own watch was moving fine. The ball would see your watch as going abnormally fast.
2. By looking at the balls watch. If the ball doesn't have a watch, you would see the normal chemical processes in the ball (say, natural deterioration of the rubber, for example) as happening slower than normal. If there were no processes that depended on time then you couldn't distinguish the two scenarios.
3. Yes. This is called gravitational redshift (normally referring to light waves)
4. For "how does time work" remember that time is really just comparing how many times one process happens compared to another. Although you think you can "intuitively" determine one second, really the way your brain tells time is by counting the number of times certainly chemical processes happen in your head. If your watch "slows down" but those chemical processes also "slow down" proportionally relative to an observer, you feel like everything is normal but the observer sees everything going slower.

Comment: Thank you, that was really clear.

Comment: Señor O: _"1. [...] the ball was wearing a watch [...] your watch [...]"_ -- For further investigation let's specify that these two watches run at equal rates (a.k.a. at "the normal rate $\nu$"), o.k.? _"you would see its watch moving slower than your watch"_ -- Right: As the ball recedes downwards (from "your watch"), "your" reception rate of seeing indications of the ball's watch is less than "the normal rate". _"The ball would see your watch as going abnormally fast."_ -- Does this hold e.g. while the ball is "falling freely" ?, or even "regardless how fast the ball is receding downwards" ?